# Is there a way to change TimeZone for a request in C# (ASP.NET MVC3)?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, localtime

Is here a way to change timezone setting for a request, for example, at **Application_AcquireRequestState**

then for the whole request, no matter when I use Datetime.ToLocalTime (or new Datetime() etc), a local time version will be shown to current user/request?

(or I have to setup timezone for everytime I use ToLocalTime )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manage TimeZone info using thread context/storage. There is no 1:1 mapping from Culture to TimeZone (*it's a many:many relationship*) ([Reference Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2938612/175679)). There are many ways to do this - such as using a custom [ThreadPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx) with context members or [Thread Local Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3671701/175679) (TLS)

Comment: thanks. I think I just have to setup timezone when each time output a time, which much easier :)

Answer (score -1):

Override InitializeCulture() in your view and set the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture properties to the culture of your choice.

Comment: Do you have some sample code, I already have code on culture, but I do not think culture and timezone are related.

Comment: You're right, DateTime.ToLocal() does not use the current culture, but [TimeZoneInfo.Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx). You can not change this value easily.